# Changing the output of counter in python

Tags: python, counter

I'm using the following code to unzip a dictionary and count the values at each site:

```
result = [Counter(site) for site in zip(*myDict.values())]
```

The output looks something like: `Counter({'A': 74}), Counter({'G': 72, 'C': 2})`
There are five possible values: `A, T, G, C`, and `N`

I only want the counter to spit out a value if one of the five values is less than 74. So for the above example, only the second would be outputted. How do you use an if statement within the counter? Furthermore, how can I label each site, so that above it could just say:

```
Site 2: 'G': 72, 'C': 2
```

myDict looks like this:

```
{'abc123': ATGGAGGACGACT, 'def332': ATGCATTGACGC}
```

Except there are 74 entries. Each value is the same length. Basically, I don't know how to use a counter that can give me an output for when each site of each value doesn't match up. So for the sequences above, the 4th site does not match. I want the counter to output the following:

```
site 4: 'G': 1, 'C': 1
```

Comment: I tried 
   for site in zip(*myDict.values()):
        if Counter(site) < 74:
            Counter(site) = result[]

Comment: What does `myDict` look like?

Comment: please clarify your question.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, I just edited the question to add myDict and tried to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) to index the sites and the [most_common](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method on [Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) can be used to check if the count is < 74.  Here's an example with just two strings:

```
from collections import Counter
myDict = {'a':'ATGTTCN','b':'ATTTCCG'}
result = [(i,Counter(site)) for i,site in enumerate(zip(*myDict.values()))]
result = [x for x in result if x[1].most_common()[0][1] < 2]
for site,count in result:
    print 'Site {}: {}'.format(site,str(count)[9:-2])
```

Output:

```
Site 2: 'T': 1, 'G': 1
Site 4: 'C': 1, 'T': 1
Site 6: 'G': 1, 'N': 1
```

Comment: When we use i,site, where is the i coming from?

Comment: `enumerate` returns a tuple of (index,value).  I added links to documentation for the methods used.

Answer (score 0):

using Dict Comprehension and only storing values if `max(Counter(x).values())<74`,
use `enumerate()` to get the `Site` number.

```
>>> mydict={'abc123': 'ATGGAGGACGACT', 'def332': 'ATGCATTGACGC'}
>>> result={'Site {}'.format(i+1):Counter(x) for i,x in enumerate(zip(*mydict.values())) if max(Counter(x).values())<2}
>>> result
{'Site 7': Counter({'T': 1, 'G': 1}), 'Site 6': Counter({'T': 1, 'G': 1}), 'Site 4': Counter({'C': 1, 'G': 1}), 'Site 9': Counter({'A': 1, 'C': 1}), 'Site 8': Counter({'A': 1, 'G': 1}), 'Site 11': Counter({'A': 1, 'G': 1}), 'Site 10': Counter({'C': 1, 'G': 1})}
```

or convert `Counter` to `dict`:

```
>>> {'Site {}'.format(i+1):dict(Counter(x)) for i,x in enumerate(zip(*mydict.values())) if max(Counter(x).values())<2}

{'Site 7': {'T': 1, 'G': 1}, 'Site 6': {'T': 1, 'G': 1}, 'Site 4': {'C': 1, 'G': 1}, 'Site 9': {'A': 1, 'C': 1}, 'Site 8': {'A': 1, 'G': 1}, 'Site 11': {'A': 1, 'G': 1}, 'Site 10': {'C': 1, 'G': 1}}
```

Comment: Yes, you can do it in one line, but it computes the Counter object twice as many times.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yes that's true, but your solution also uses two list comprehensions.

Comment: It was slightly faster that way (verified with timeit, although after the fact :^) )